# What does a default constructor means in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, constructor, default-constructor

Based on what I have read, a constructor can have two meanings:

> In computer programming languages the term default constructor can
>   refer to a constructor that is automatically generated by the compiler
>   in the absence of any programmer-defined constructors (e.g. in Java)

and

> In other languages (e.g. in C++) it is a constructor that can be
>   called without having to provide any arguments, irrespective of
>   whether the constructor is auto-generated or used-defined

So in the context of C#, what does a default constructor means, does it mean a constructor that is auto-generated and its only job is to initialize the members to some default values?

Comment: Please do more research and read pages like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Regardless of the answer, keep in mind that since "default constructor" has two common different meanings, people are likely to use the term incorrectly.

Comment: [C# Basics Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/) I'd suggest keeping this close by in cases like this also `MSDN` has tons of educational documentation and examples as well...

Comment: then find on / use one that works.. cheers

Answer (score 6):

In C# the default constructor is an empty constructor (with no parameters) generated for you by the compiler when you don't define any constructors.

Answer (score 5):

Default constructor in C# is, by definition, a constructor with such signature:

```
Class()
{

}
```

No parameters are provided here, so the compiler can call this method without any doubts. If your class is providing some other constructors, the default one woudn't be generated by a compiler and you have to add it manually:

```
Class() : this(null)
{
}

Class(object data)
{

}
```

In default constructor you can define your logic for a class which is respresenting it's state, such as a private fields or outer components. The other purpose of the default constructors can be found in Dependency Injection containers, there it used for a default instantiation of the object you are mapping.

Comment: and the job is to...? The OP wondered about the actual purpose of one. (for example, default value initialization, providing the program some default to fall back on, etc.)

Comment: Yes, but the question is, is any constructor with such a signature a default constructor? And the answer to that seems to be no: only the compiler-generated parameterless constructor is called "default constructor", a user-provided parameterless constructor isn't.

Comment: @VMAtm Sorry, but that's wrong. In a default constructor you can't define anything. If you define the constructor yourself, it stops being a default constructor, because "default constructor" *only* refers to the constructor automatically created for you by the compiler. It normally wouldn't matter, but the whole point of this question is specifically what "default constructor" means, so mis-using it in your answer is likely to cause confusion.

Comment: @hvd If you define a field like this: Int d = 5; it'll be in a default constructor.

Comment: @VMAtm From a C# perspective, it won't be in the constructor. From a CIL perspective, it will be in the constructor, but there's no concept of a default constructor. (A C# default constructor and a C# empty user-provided parameterless constructor are indistinguishable in CIL.)

Answer (score 2):

The default constructor in C# is an auto-generated constructor in case you haven't provided any. In that case the compiler will add the default public constructor which accepts no arguments.
However, as soon as you'll define any constructor, the default constructor won't be available any more.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, the default constructor and the parameterless constructor are effectively synonymous. ie:

```
public MyClass()
{
}
```

Note that like in C++, providing a parameterized constructor removes the "provided" default one. You can always add a default/parameterless definition though.

Answer (score 0):

Default constructor is parameterless constructor.

See: [10.10.4 Default constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> If a class contains **no instance constructor declarations**, a
>   default instance constructor is automatically provided.

Answer (score 0):

A default constructor is parameterless and is provided when the class contains no instance constructor declarations.

Try [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)